# transformation/metadata with infer_schema function

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a procedurer created in Snowflake that uses the infer_schema function to dynamically create a table based on the structure of the files loaded to an internal stage. There's currently six different files in the stage. The process is doing exactly what I want. However, I was wondering if there's a way to add file name as a column in the table.

This is what I have:

```
Create or replace table t1
     using template (
         select array_agg(object_construct(*))
           from table(
              infer_schema(
                 location => 'stage'
                   file_format => 'file_format'
                     )
                      )
                           );

copy into t1
from @stage
file_format = 'file_format'
match_by_column_name = case_insensitive;
```

While this works, I want a column with file name added. Normally, I would do

```
copy into t1
select metadate$filename
from stage
```

but I'm not sure how I can accomplish that here.

Comment: Have you looking into using a dynamic scripting (SP or Snowflake scripting) to read the definition of t1 after it has been created, and then use the table definition to specify columns in your copy into statement?  In theory, you could simply add a filename column to t1 with an alter table statement, and then script the copy into with a select that specifies columns.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to do this in a single `create table using template` statement. However, you can chain a subsequent `create table as select` statement to add any additional columns you may want:

```sql
create table T0
using template (
    select *
    from table(
        infer_schema(
            location => '@STAGE_NAME',
            file_format => 'FILE_FORMAT_NAME'
        )
    )
);

create table T1
as (
    select
        *,
        null::varchar as MY_COLUMN_NAME
    from T0
    limit 0
);

drop table T0;
```

In the preceding example, "T1" is your desired table name whereas "T0" is merely any placeholder table name.

The `limit 0` clause in the `create table as select` statement causes that query to return only the column definitions of T0 instead of any actual data. In effect, this lets you copy *the definition* of T0 in an extensible way. Namely, it lets you prepend/append additional columns.

Note that this techniques requires you to provide a "dummy expression" that evaluates to the intended type for each additional column. This is because we are defining T1 as the *inferred* schema of a query instead of as the explicit schema of a typed column list. Fortunately, since no rows are actually returned/inserted (due to the `limit 0`), we can provide a dummy expression by simply casting `null` to the intended data type.